# Overriding issues with Java (inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

Calculate area of a square or rectangle.
Help, so I have to apply inheritance, overriding, perhaps overloading depending on the statement, here when I try to calculate the rectangle's area the result is 0.0 I believe it's because my asignar (assign) method in the subclass isn't overriding the one from the superclass.
Also, does this program effectively apply inheritance and overriding(besides the issue i'm having)?

```
import java.io.*;

class AreaF {
    private double lado; // side

    public void asignar(double b) {
        lado = b;
    }

    public double traerL() {
        return lado;
    }
}

class Cuadrado extends AreaF {
    public double area() {
        double a;
        a = Math.pow(traerL(), 2);
        return a;
    }
}

class Rectangulo extends AreaF {
    private double altura; // height

    public void asignar(double h) {
        double altura = h;
    }

    public double area() {
        double a;
        a = traerL() * altura;
        return a;
    }
}

public class Pro2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double b = 0, h = 0;
        int op;
        Cuadrado obj = new Cuadrado(); // square
        Rectangulo obj2 = new Rectangulo(); // rectangle
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Ingrese la base: ");
        try {
            b = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        obj.asignar(b);
         /**
         * 1 - for square
         * 2 - for rectangle
         */
        System.out.println("Ingrese 1 para saber el area de CUADRADO, 2 para RECTANGULO"); 

        op = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (op == 1) {
            System.out.println("El area del cuadrado es: " + obj.area()); // sq
                                                                            // area
        } else if (op == 2) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la altura del rectangulo: "); // height
            try {
                h = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            obj2.asignar(h);
            System.out.println("El area del rectangulo es: " + obj2.area()); // rct
                                                                                // area
        } else
            System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but to me class hierarchy looks strange:
1. What is the benefit of class `AreaF` which has "side"? 2. To me looks like `Cuadrado` must be inherited from `Rectangulo` as a square is the edge case of rectangle where both height and width are equals.

Comment: Your main problem is that you created two objects `obj` and `obj2` when you ask to insert the base you only set it up on the `obj` here `obj.asignar(b);` after that you ask if it is a rectangle or a square when the user chose a rectangle you never setted `obj2.asignar(b);` therefore you will always have 0 for a rectangle.

Comment: Well, if you want to Square and Rectangle to extend AreaF, I would suggest changing it to an interface with a function to return the area. As it is now, you are technically overriding (add optional `@Override` annotation).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what is the goal of this task, but I would go with the following class hierarchy:

```
interface Figure { // also abstract class can be used there
    abstract double area();
}

class Rectangle implements Figure {
    private double width;
    private double height;

    Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    double area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
    public Square(double side) {
        super(side, side);
    }
}
```

I simplified `main` method, but I think the idea is clear:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(3, 5);
    System.out.println("rectangle.area() = " + rectangle.area()); // result is 15.0
    final Square square = new Square(3);
    System.out.println("square.area() = " + square.area()); // result is 9.0
}
```

So, `Rectangle` overrides `area()` method of `Figure` and `Square` inherits it from `Rectangle`.

Comment: Given the requirements that the OP has mentioned and the design you have implemented, don't you think using an *interface* would be better suited, instead of an *abstract class*? Especially since `Figure` does not have (and/or require) any implemented methods. For more clarity on the distinction between the two, [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo).

Comment: I agree. Actually my first idea was to create it as an interface(I would definitely do it in production code), but then I changed my mind. I thought that maybe with abstract class the idea of inheritance would be more clear to topic starter. But if at least we two think that interface is better here, I edited my post :)

Comment: Yea, I figured as much. Nice design and answer, either way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are neither overloading nor overriding. You're just hiding.

Overloading refers to the addition of a method in a class in which a method with the same name but different signatures already exists.

Overriding refers to the addition of a method marked with the `@Override` attribute in a class whose super class contains a method with the same name and signature.

Hiding is similar to overriding, but the method added is not marked with `@Override`, which is what you have done here.

So the answer to this question

> does this program effectively apply inheritance and overriding(besides the issue I'm having)?

is *no*.

I think you should change your whole design.

Note: All of below is my own opinion.

`AreaF` should be an abstract class, or even an interface. I think an interface is more suitable, but it seems like that your assignment needs you to use inheritance. So let's change it to an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AreaF {
    public abstract double getArea();
}
```

I see that you have a square and a rectangle as the base class of `AreaF`. Let's implement them as well:

```
public class Square extends AreaF {
    private double length;
    public double getLength() { return length; }
    public void setLength(double length) { this.length = length; }
    @Override // I overrode the getArea method in the super class
    public double getArea() {
        return getLength() * getLength();
    }
}
```

And here is the Rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle extends AreaF {
    private double width, height;

    // public getters and setters for width and height. You know what I mean.
    @Override
    public double getArea () {
        return getWidth() * getHeight();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the methods accordingly and get the correct result.

Comment: What? @Override is optional in Java (good practice, but optional). What's the semantic difference between "hiding" and "overriding" as you define them?

Comment: What is the benefit of having different `getArea()` methods for `Rectangle` and `Square` if they do exact the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had lots of problems.
1)indent
2)English names.
3)you had a logic Error. Object1.lado=a, Object1.altura=0; while Object2.lado=0, Object2.altura=h ==> obj2.area=0... (this is your mistake!).

here is a good code. look at it and if you have any quotation feel free to ask.

```
import java.io.*;

class AreaF {
    private final double lado; 

    public void asignarLado(double b) { //give mingfullnames (better in english!)
        lado = b;
    }

    public double traerL() {
        return lado;
    }
}

class Cuadrado extends AreaF {
    public double areaCuadrado() {
        double a;
        a = Math.pow(traerL(), 2);
        return a;
    }
}

class Rectangulo extends Cuadrado {
    private double altura; 

    public void asignarAltura(double h) {
        double altura = h;
    }

    public double areaRectangulo() {
        double a;
        a = traerL() * altura;
        return a;
    }
}



public class Pro2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double b = 0, h = 0;
        int op;
        Cuadrado obj = new Cuadrado(); // square

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la base: ");
            b = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            obj.asignarBase(b);

            System.out.println("Ingrese la altura del rectangulo: "); // height
            h = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            obj.asignarAltura(h);

            System.out.println("Ingrese 1 para saber el area de CUADRADO, 2 para RECTANGULO");
            op = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

             if (op == 1) {
                System.out.println("El area del cuadrado es: " + obj.areaCuadrado());
             else if (op == 2) {
                System.out.println("El area del rectangulo es: " + obj.areaRectangulo());
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            System.out.println("Wrong arguments!");
        }finally{
            br.close; //allways close input resurce! 
        }

    }
}
```

///-------------------------------------------
And this is real O.O design. 
I used an interface with one method called Area.
and two classes cube, and rect classes. this is the real way to go.

```
public interface Area{
    public double getArea();
}

class Cuadrado implements Area {
    double base;

    public Cuadrado(double base){
        setBase(base);
    }

    public void setBase(double base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base*base;
    }


}

class Rectangulo extends Cuadrado {

    private double hight;

    public Rectangulo(double base,double hight){
        super(base);
        this.hight = hight;
    }

    public void setParams(double base,double hight) {
        this.base = base;
        this.hight = hight;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return base*hight;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la base: ");
            double b = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

            System.out.println("Ingrese la altura del rectangulo: "); // height
            double h = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

            System.out.println("Ingrese 1 para saber el area de CUADRADO, 2 para RECTANGULO");
            int op = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

             if (op == 1) {
                Area cuadrado = new Cuadrado(b); // square
                System.out.println("El area del cuadrado es: " + cuadrado.getArea());
             }
             else if (op == 2) {
                Area rectangulo = new Rectangulo(b,h);
                System.out.println("El area del rectangulo es: " + rectangulo.getArea());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
            System.out.println("Wrong arguments!");
        }finally{
            br.close(); //allways close input resurce! 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: as an answer, this is quite low quality; should be a comment.

Comment: Firstly, I didn't give a '-1'. I chose to notify you instead. Secondly, that is simply **not** a reason to put a comment as an answer.

Comment: but my answer is true... the root of the problem is indeed lies in the fact that ob1 and obj2 are to different objects.. :)
His code has X10000 problems. but the biggest one is obj1 and obj2 are two distinct Objects.

Comment: Please refer to the other answers posted in this thread, especially the one by @AndrejIstomin. Please also look at [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good point about bad code formatting. I would also agree with using English language in code. But I completely disagree with the form of your comment. It's impolite. Comment which is starting with words: "I did not look at you code entirely..." is really worth to get "-1", isn't it?

Comment: I did not mean to be impolite, I meant that maybe there other errors, but for now i see this logic error... did not mean to be impolite.